# "lvalue required as left operand of assignment" al usar &&

Tags: c++

Empecé hace un par de días en C++, y al intentar hacer un ejercicio de Codecademy, mi consola me tira error. Si bien dentro del Codeacademy me reconoce como correcto el ejercicio, al intentar compilarlo por mi cuenta el resultado es otro.
Mi código, seguido del error en cuestión:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int year;
  cin >> year;
  bool leap;
  if (year>999 && year<10000){
    if(year%4==0){
      if(year%100==0 && year%400=!0){
        leap=false;
      }else{
        leap=true;
      }
    }
  }
  cout << "The year is " << leap;
}
```

```
Leap_Year.cpp:9:22: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
    9 |       if(year%100==0 && year%400=!0){
      |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Tienes un *typo*. No es `=!`, es `!=`: `if( year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0 )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendas por estar en inglés. Te lo traduzco:

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

> error: se requiere un valor izquierdo como operando izquierdo de una asignación

En C++ se pueden clasificar los datos en diferentes categorías, una de las categorías más genéricas es la de valores de lado izquierdo (**l**eft **value**) y valores de lado derecho (**r**ight **value**).

A grandes rasgos, los valores de lado izquierdo son aquellos datos que pueden ir a la izquierda de una igualación... es decir: aquellos a los que se les puede asignar valor. Mientras que los valores de lado derecho son aquellos datos que pueden ir a la derecha de una igualación... es decir: aquellos que son un valor a asignar.

Sabiendo eso ya entiendes la primera parte de tu error, ahora veamos la expresión que has redactado:

```
year%100==0 && year%400=!0
```

Por precedencia de operadores se ejecutará en este orden:

```
         Asignación_____    ____ Operador de negación booleana
                        \  / 
                         vv
  year%100==0 && year%400=!0
1                         !0
2                year%400
3 year%100
4         ==
5             &&
6                        =
```

Asumiendo que `year` sea 2021:

1. `!0` pasa a ser `true`.
2. `2021%400` pasa a ser `21`.
3. `2021%100` pasa a ser `21`

Por lo que al final queda esta expresión:

```
21==0 && 21=true
```

El número `21` es un valor de lado derecho, por lo que no se le puede asignar un valor y por eso tienes el error que describes.

---

Seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
year%100==0 && year%400!=0
//                     ^^ <--- Operador 'diferente de'
```

Answer (score 0):

Una pequeña contribución.  lvalue (r-valor) y rvalue (r-valor) se refieren a **expresiones**, y no a valores.

Si gustas leer la documentación en español que explica más profundamente lo que otros han respondido, puedes consultar la documentación en español para las categorías de valor en es.cppreference.com:

[Categorías de valor](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)